# How to run Python file in Heroku from termux(Andriod)?

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, heroku

I am getting error when trying to run my python file from termux can any one help me pls.

```
heroku run --app python popfinal.py

Running popfinal.py on ⬢ python... done

     ›   Error: You do not have permission to manage dynos
     ›   on python. You need to have the deploy or operate
     ›   permission on this app.
     ›
     ›   Error ID: forbidden
```

Comment: The error seems pretty clear.  Do you think you have permission to manage dynos?

Comment: yes i have. some how its not working i restart it.

Answer (score 0):

```
heroku run --app python popfinal.py Running popfinal.py on ⬢ python... 
done › Error: You do not have permission to manage dynos › on python. 
You need to have the deploy or operate › permission on this app. › › Error ID: forbidden
```

You need to authenticate first before being able to run that command. You can authenticate with `heroku login`.

**If** that still does not work then I'm afraid that the issue runs much deeper and is something you will have to ask the maintainers of the termux project to fix. [Termux is not a true Linux environment](https://wiki.termux.com/wiki/Differences_from_Linux). Some stuff may be broken. So the heroku CLI functionalities might not entirely work on Termux.